# Modern USB dock: is PD on 2012 Macbook Pro with USB-A going to damage the computer?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware, dock, power

I bought a UGREEN 6-in-1 USB dock to expand my 2012 Macbook Pro's capabilities (can't currently afford anything new).

The dock has a USB-C connector to the computer, which has only USB-A 2.0 ports, for which I'm using a USB-C to USB-A adapter from UGREEN too. It works great.

However, I can only connect one USB device to the dock, as connecting anything else makes other device connections fail; I presume it's because there's not enough current to keep all connected devices powered.

The thing is, this dock also has a USB-C PD input, which could keep connected devices powered whilst providing power to a USB-C laptop such as modern Mx Macbooks.
However, since the 2012 Macbook Pro doesn't have native USB-C ports nor does it know about USB-PD, here comes my question:

If I connected a USB-C power supply to the dock's USB-PD input to keep connected devices powered (say, a 45W power adapter), would this power input damage the USB-A connection to the laptop, or would the laptop's USB-A ignore it?